# Period of sum of periodic functions

Tags: education, periodic-functions

Why is the following function:

$$f(t) = \sin(2\pi\cdot10^6t) + \sin(2\pi\cdot10^6t) \sin(2\pi\cdot1000t)$$

periodic, whereas

$$f(t) = 10\cdot \sin(2\pi\cdot10^6t) + 10\cdot 0.5\cdot \sin(2\pi\cdot10^6t) \sin(2\pi\cdot1000t)$$

is not periodic?

Comment: Hi @Clement C., I calculated the period of the two functions with "FunctionPeriod" in Wolfram Mathematica. The first has period 0.001, the second is not periodic.

Comment: For the second $f(t+1)=f(t)$, for example. The function *is* periodic, see e.g. http://goo.gl/mQSjEp

Comment: Hi @Clement C., Wolfram Alpha does not calculate the period (only Wolfram Alpha Pro do it).

Comment: You do **not** need Wolfram to do it for you -- you can check by hand that $f(t+\frac{1}{1000})=f(t)$ (for instance).

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica (which is the engine running under WolframAlpha) treats any decimal values such as 0.5 as imprecise decimal approximations. As such it reports there is no period as it is not treating 0.5 as exactly equal to $\frac{1}{2}$. If you replace the $0.5$ with $1/2$ in the input to WolframAlpha it will give you that the period is $\frac{1}{1000}$.

Comment: Or replace $10
\cdot 0.5$ by $5$.